# How can I check check should contain multiple properties with chai-things?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, chai

I am looking to check an array contains an Object on my mocha tests for my Node.js application and I know with [Chai-Things](http://chaijs.com/plugins/chai-things) I can do:

```
[{ pet: 'cat' }, { pet: 'dog' }].should.include({ pet: 'cat' })
```

or

```
[{ pet: 'cat' }, { pet: 'dog' }].should.contain.a.thing.with.property('pet', 'cat')
```

but is there a way to check if contains multiple properties without knowing all properties
For example if I had an array:

```
var arr = [{ pet: 'cat', owner:1, id:1 }, { pet: 'cat', owner:2, id:2 },{ pet: 'dog', owner:1, id:3 }]
```

And I wanted to check for an Object containing `{ pet: 'cat', owner:1}` I do not know what the id before test as this will be generated randomly

how might I do this in an efficient manner, preferably with chai, chai plugin or vanilla js as I cannot use another framework. I looked at [Chai-fuzzy](http://chaijs.com/plugins/chai-fuzzy) but I don't think this would help from my understanding

Comment: can you just add 2 statements to get the logic you need?  `arr.should.contain.a.thing.with.property('pet', 'cat');`  ...   `arr.should.contain.a.thing.with.property('owner', 1);`   I would file a ticket on github for chai-things and see what they say.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand, you want to filter the javascript array of objects. You can use a jquery api **grep** as following.

```
filter = $.grep(arr, function (v) {
        return v.pet === "cat" && v.owner === 1;
});
```

Hope it helps....

Comment: apologies maybe I wasn't clear in the question but this is server side javascript and  I did also say that I cannot use another framework, but good to know it exists